# maintaining user session on WCF Clients while making calls to servers behind a load balance

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, load-balancing, keep-alive

My problem is the following:
 - I have a .Net MVC site making a lot of calls to WCF services hosted in two server behind a load balancing server (BIGip).

I do have to maintain a user session on the WCF services (controlled by a custom token).
My problem is that the sticky session is not working when a lot of users is logged on the site (a lot of concurrent calls to the services).

What I figured out was that when the site calls the service reusing a existing connection, the load balancing server ignores the sticky session cookie and forwards the request to the last server that received a call by this connection.

I checked using sniffer (Wireshark), and every call is sent to the load balancing server with the correct sticky session token.

When a connection is created from scratch the stick session cookie is taken into account and the request goes to the right server.

So, how can I handle that situation?
I'm looking for something that enforces creating a new connection on each call, but the property KeepAliveEnabled="false" is not working.

Tks.

Comment: Try to make it pseudo state-less by moving the session data into a synchronized store like a database or AppFabric

Comment: It is my workaround solution, but I'm avoiding this now, Tks!

Comment: Note, that sticky sessions create problems in case a machine is down for patching, deployment or repair. This makes them an infeasible solution most of the time.

Comment: I do know the problems involving sticky session, however I have not power on that project to avoid its use. Considering what I read ultimately it is possible to control the server that will respond the request sending the correct cookie, but I don't know why the load balancing server is ignoring it in reused connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solve using the correct keepAliveConnection configuration to Framework 4.
Bellow are the configs.

The wrong one

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceSessionCreator" keepAliveEnabled="false">
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

The correct one

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IServiceSessionCreator" >
      <textMessageEncoding />
      <httpTransport allowCookies="false" keepAliveEnabled="false"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

I don't know why the first one did not work.
I saw it in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms730128(v=vs.100).aspx